# Some questions about memory allocation in C

Tags: c

So I have defined a structure `struct process` with `name` as of its attributs. I also a global variable `struct process *table[3]`.

So inside one of my functions, I did:

```
struct process *new_element =  table[0];
new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct process));
new_element->name = some_name;
...
```

After that, when I try to access the name with `table[0]->name` it shows me an memory access error.

But if I use `malloc` on `table[0]` it works:

```
table[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct process));
struct process *new_element = table[0];
new_element->name = some_name;
...
```

I dont understand why the first case failed, when I point `new_element` towards `table[0]` then use `malloc` on it, shouldnt it allocates memory on `table[0]`?

Comment: You misunderstand pointers. You didn't point new_element towards table[0], you **copied** the pointer from table[0] to new_element. Pointers are values too. Of course changing new_element has no effect at all on table[0]. Think about this `int x[3]; int y = x[0]; y = 33;` Would you expect `x[0]` to be `33` now? But that is exactly the same as your code.

Comment: Just  because you are using pointers doesn't mean that the normal rules about variables and assignment are changed. There's nothing special about pointers, the normal rules apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> struct process *new_element =  table[0];
> ```

This copies the pointer (which is a value, similar to an integer) into a new variable called `new_element`. When you modify it later (assigning it what `malloc()` returns), `table[0]` is not updated.

> shouldnt it allocates memory on table[0]?

No, it does not. The address is saved to `new_element`, but `table[0]` is not modified. If you want to do it that way, you would need to copy the address later on:

```
table[0] = new_element;
```

This doesn`t copy the element, just the pointer (the address of where it is in memory)!

Answer (score 0):

When yo do this:

```
struct process *new_element =  table[0]; // this make variable points to memory table[0]
new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct process)); // in this point you don't creating memory for table[0] you are creating memory and assigning th
```

at to new_element
new_element->name = some_name; // here is an new memory

After that, when yo try table[0]->name. here is not memory table[0] is undefined

```
table[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct process)); // Here you create a memory for table[0]
struct process *new_element = table[0]; // here you point to the memory wich table[0] points to
new_element->name = some_name; // Here is not undefined and can be accesible
```